# Protractor to wait for page to load JS script before continuing?

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests

My protractor test(not angular) is failing due to an extra JS script being loaded to the page. I tried .then but up to no luck. The extra JS being added is not an XHR request. I assume it is included in the package and just waiting to be called.

Long version:
After clicking to a button, user will be redirected to a new page. 
However, in this new page, a JS script is being added in along with some images. This creates a new load time. The problem is that protractor is clicking while the page is still loading this JS and other things.

I tried Using .then() but no luck. I assume it only waits for server responses.

I was able to make it run but by adding browser.sleep(). I know this is not a good practice so I am still researching.

My sample of .then code snippet

```
element(by.css("[type='submit']")).click().then(function(){
//Enter payment info
element(by.css(".number[type='text']")).sendKeys(data.validCard); //Mastercard
element(by.css("select.exp_month")).element(by.css("[value='05']")).click();
element(by.css("select.exp_year")).element(by.css("[value='2021']")).click();
element(by.css("input.cvc[type='text']")).sendKeys("1234");
element(by.css("input.full-name[type='text']")).clear().sendKeys(randomName);
elm = element(by.css("button[type='submit']"));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 60000);
element(by.css("button[type='submit']")).click();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you know this, but just to be clear, a `.then` is used to wait for a promise to resolve, not an element. You correctly are using a wait, to wait for the page to load, but the target should be for an indication of the page being loaded, and perhaps not the button itself... unless they are the same thing.

First off, though this might not be the answer, `presenceOf` will return when the button is *in the dom*, and perhaps not yet visible. I find it's usually better to use `isClickable` in these cases.

Ultimately, you just need to find a condition in the dom that occurs when the js is done loading, and wait for that.